# C FIFO Queue linked list with timer

Tags: c, timer, linked-list, fifo

I need to implement the FIFO link-list queue that can layout with current elements and enqueue/dequeue/exit option for user selection.
If enqueue option is selected, enter a string and enqueue this string. If dequeue is selected, dequeue one element.
In the meantime, the program keeps dequeue one element per 5 seconds and enqueue one element (ex: a1, a2, a3,…) per 10 seconds.
After enqueue/dequeue to or from the link-list, show the current elements in queue and ready for the next selection.
The UI updates/refresh when enqueue(10sec)/dequeue(5sec)/exit. If there is no element in queue or no selection is input, no update is needed.

Here’s the data structure.

```
QElement* head;
QElement* tail;

typedef struct{
  char element[20];
  QElement* next;
}QElement;

enq();
deq();
```

---

Example scenario:

Current Element: N/A
Current Time: 17:59:12
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):    ß No input
Element: a1 is enqueued.                    ß 10 sec from 17:59:12

Current Element: a1
Current Time: 17:59:22
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):    ß No input
Element: a1 is dequeued.                    ß 5 sec from 17:59:22

Current Element: N/A
Current Time: 17:59:27
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):1
Please enter the string: ABC
Element: ABC is enqueued.

Current Element: ABC
Current Time: 17:59:28
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):1
Please enter the string: DEF
Element: DEF is enqueued.

Current Element: ABC->DEF
Current Time: 17:59:29
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):
Element: a2 is enqueued.                   ß 10 sec from 17:59:22
Element: ABC is dequeued.                 ß 5 sec from 17:59:27

Current Element: DEF->a2
Current Time: 17:59:32
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):
Please enter the string: IJK
Element: IJK is enqueued.

Current Element: DEF->a2->IJK
Current Time: 17:59:34
Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):

my code is not completed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct A{
    char element[20];
    struct QElement* next;
    }QElement;

QElement* head = NULL;
QElement* tail = NULL;




int main()
{
char data[] = "a";
int i = 2;
while(i--) {

    if (Isitempty(head,tail)) {
        printf("Current Element: N/A\n");
    }
    else {
        Print();
    }
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    printf("Current time: %s",ctime(&now));
    printf("Please enter the option(1.Enq; 2. Deq, 3.Exit):\n");
    //SetTimer(NULL, 1, 100, enq(data));

    enq(data);
    enq(data);
}




return 0;
}


int Isitempty(QElement* front,QElement* end) {
if (front==NULL && end == NULL) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void enq(char data[]) {
QElement* temp = (QElement*)malloc(sizeof(QElement));

strcpy(temp->element,data);
temp->next = NULL;
if (head == NULL && tail == NULL) {
    head = temp;
    tail = temp;

    printf("Element: %s is enqueued\n", temp->element);


    return;
}
tail->next = temp;
tail = temp;

printf("Element: %s is enqueued\n", temp->element);


free(temp);
return;
}

void Print() {
QElement* temp = (QElement*) malloc(sizeof(QElement));
temp = head;

for (temp ; temp != NULL ; temp=temp->next) {
    printf("Current Element: %s",temp->element);
    //temp = temp->next;
}
}
```

idk why in the Print() function, the for loop will not end? I think temp must be NULL at the end. But it doesn't work. I don't really know how to handle the timer and user select enq/deq/exit. Please can someone help me?

Comment: Delete `free(temp);` at `enq`.

Comment: Also `typedef struct A{` --> `typedef struct QElement{`, `QElement* temp = (QElement*) malloc(sizeof(QElement));
temp = head;` --> `QElement* temp = head;` at `Print`.

Comment: Why are you initializing `temp` outside the for loop?  Just do `for (temp=head; ...`.  Also, there is no need to malloc memory for temp since you never use it.

Comment: and don't `malloc()` memory for `temp` if you reassign the pointer in the next line. That just causes a memory leak